# The class ClientType is missing from package com.hazelcast.core from version 4.0 up

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast

Hie guys please assist. I have been going through the documentation and the class ClientType in package com.hazelcast.core is missing. In version 3.12 the class exists and then in v4.0 upwards the class mysteriously disappears. Where did the class go. Please assist.

Comment: In 4.0, there were lots of refactorings to get rid of some technical debts, and the class might be removed during the process. Could you tell me what you want to achieve with this class? I might suggest some alternative ways, after understanding your use case

Comment: I want to get the ClientType. For me to achieve that I need the ClientType class. I have been trying to find where it was moved to. If it was been totally removed how does one get the clienttype.

Comment: It does not exist anymore. Can you describe how you were getting the client type, and what you were trying to do with it?

The closest thing to that is [this API](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/client/Client.java#L54), which has one of the following [values](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/internal/nio/ConnectionType.java)

But, before posting this as the answer, I need to verify that it suits your needs

Answer (score 0):

They may have removed the class, but to be sure you can manually go to the same location in .m2 folder and search the file. This is can be done easily if you are using an IDE. So if the class is missing, either you might need to change the way you used to do the task with new version's classes or if there are few dependencies, you may write the same class by you too( not good if ClientType class has too much dependencies from the library).

Comment: I am currently upgrading from Hazelcast v3.12 to v5.0 . My question then becomes if it was removed completely how does one then get the client type?

Comment: That's why I'm saying if it is not there there should be another way around. You may have to research and change your classes to the new way

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the solution to this for anyone who might be in a similar situation as me. The class I am looking for which is "com.hazelcast.core.ClientType" is nolonger required since the client type field in Client was changed from ClientType to type String. Hence there is no need for the ClientType class.